# How to extend bootstrap by own styles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have installed bootstrap 4.5 into RAILS 6 and I want to extend some styles.

For that I have a file named banana.scss in app/assets/stylesheets that looks like this :

```
.form-read-only {
 @extend .form-control, .form-control-sm;
 background-color: rgb(233, 236, 239)
}
```

Now I want to embed this stylesheet after bootstrap is loaded, so I have modified the app/assets/stylesheets/application.css by

```
/*
 ...
 *= require banana
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
*/

@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'banana';
```

But this leads to the error message in the browser to :

```
Error: The target selector was not found.
       Use "@extend .form-control-sm !optional" to avoid this error.
        on line 5 of app/assets/stylesheets/banana.scss
>>   @extend .form-control, .form-control-sm;
```

But what is the remmmended way to extand bootstrap ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only issue is that you `*= require banana` before you `@import 'bootstrap'`. Try removing the first one:

```
/*
 ...
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
*/

@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'banana';
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an easy way to accomplish that.

Just import the bootstrap on the beginning of my custom stylesheet:

```
@import 'bootstrap';

.form-read-only {
  @extend .form-control, .form-control-sm;
  background-color: rgb(233, 236, 239)
}
```

Because I can't define the order in which the stylesheet files are loaded, here I'm sure when the custom stylesheet is loaded, in front of the depending bootstrap stylesheets are loaded at first.